Ceres-solver does not find local glog and gflags
I want to build ceres-solver locally, however, it keeps finding the gflags and glog libraries under my python installation instead of under the standard gnu install directories
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/cmake

Why does it first look in obscure places such as
~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda/lib

instead of the usual locations? Running ceres-solver with the versions in python leads to a GLIBCXX_3.4.32 not found error. I don't want to interfere with my anaconda installation regarding libstdc++ and just have the correct version in the standard locations.

This was a consequence of
~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda/bin

being ahead of
/usr/local/bin

in the PATH variable.
